# Background image to fit 3.5" and 4" screens

Tags: ios, iphone

I have been looking online for a while now on how to make my images fit the iPhones 3.5" screen and 4" screen but i cant find anything.

I have a -568@2x.png image, a image.png, and a image@2x.png but when i run the simulator for the 
iPhone 3.5" the image is stretched to far to the right.

I need help to fix this, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of a Background image. Just add a UIImageView and which displays an image depending on screen size. (You will need to make two sets of images for this so you don't get any stretching).

You can then set which image to be displayed in the UIImageView by adding a simple if statement to check which screen size you have in the viewDidLoad method like this:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    if (result.height == 480) {
        // 3.5 inch display
        [background_image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"small_background.png"]];
    }

    else if (result.height == 568) {
        // 4 inch display
        [background_image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"big_background.png"]];
    }
}
```

Don't forget to declare "background_image" as a UIImageView in your header file:

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *background_image;
```

Comment: Could you send me a private message, i have questions that i would like to ask about my first app. You seem to know your stuff and advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please may you send me an email. My email is: supertecnoboff@me.com   -   Thanks for the tick :)